# Bypass network search on boot

Tags: macos, high-sierra, bootcamp

Is there a way to bypass the network search when booting with the Option key? I switch between macOS and Windows with Bootcamp, and while the partitions come up quickly, I can‘t choose one before the wifi search is over. It‘s only slightly annoying, but still annoying.

Comment: Why do you need to use the option key? Can you not choose the operating system directly from the current booted operating system? Would you consider use a third party boot managers such as rEFInd?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, David! It seems I would be able to boot to macOS from Windows (can‘t check now), but how would I boot to Win from macOS? Selecting startup disk every time would be even more annoying than a delay with option key :)